# Function Key on 68 keys keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, function-keys

I'm new to Linux in general.

Currently I am using a 68 keys keyboard (FL-Esport CMK68).

- In Windows when I press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> ==> `Function 1 key(F1)`.
- In Ubuntu when pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> ==> `Function Screen Brightness Reduce`.

Anyone know a fix to this or maybe a workaround?